# How to cover a setTimeout function with a document spy in Jasmine / Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a `setTimeout` inside my `ngOnInit` to define some properties and run a function.
I want to unit test this but it doesn't go in the `setTimeout`, tried to use `tick()` and `fakeAsync`.

My code to cover with Jasmine unit test:

```
ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.container = document.querySelector(`#field-${this.id}`);
      this.inputField = document.querySelector(`#${this.id}`);

      this.getState();
    }, 50);
}

getState() {
    this.inputField.addEventListener('focus', () => {
      const tooltip = this.container.querySelector('.tooltip');
      const tooltipHeight = tooltip.querySelector('p').clientHeight;

      tooltip.style.height = tooltipHeight + 'px';
    });

    this.inputField.addEventListener('blur', () => {
      const tooltip = this.container.querySelector('.tooltip');

      tooltip.style.height = '0px';
    });
}
```

What I did to cover this:

```
it('should ', fakeAsync(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TooltipComponent);
    const componentInst = fixture.componentInstance;
    componentInst.id = 'fieldId';

    
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        const tooltipContainer = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#fieldId'));
        expect(componentInst.container ).toBe(tooltipContainer );
    });
}));
```

But this doesn't go inside the `setTimeout` function, I think I need to spy on `document.querySelector`.

How can I cover this `setTimeout` function?

Comment: you need to call `tick()` after the timer is registered, which is after the `ngOnInit()` is called (put `tick()` after `fixture.detectChanges()`)

Comment: @MikeS. yes I tried also that, but still the same. It doesn't go inside the `setTimeout(() => {`

Comment: `tick()` just resolves promises. You have to put a number to be specific how much time you want to elapse. So do what @MikeS. said as well as put `tick(50)` instead of `tick()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `ngOnInit` method of the component, then call `tick(50)`;

In order to call `ngOnInit`, you should call `fixture.detectChanges()` firstly.

The [doc](https://angular.io/guide/testing-utility-apis#componentfixture-methods) about `detectChanges`:

> Call it to initialize the component (it calls ngOnInit) and after your test code, change the component's data bound property values

An working example:

`tooltip.component.ts`:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tooltip',
  template: `<div [id]="'field-' + id">
    <input [id]="id" />
  </div>`,
})
export class TooltipComponent implements OnInit {
  id = 'name';
  container: any;
  inputField: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.container = document.querySelector(`#field-${this.id}`);
      this.inputField = document.querySelector(`#${this.id}`);

      this.getState();
    }, 50);
  }

  getState() {
    this.inputField.addEventListener('focus', () => {
      const tooltip = this.container.querySelector('.tooltip');
      const tooltipHeight = tooltip.querySelector('p').clientHeight;

      tooltip.style.height = tooltipHeight + 'px';
    });

    this.inputField.addEventListener('blur', () => {
      const tooltip = this.container.querySelector('.tooltip');

      tooltip.style.height = '0px';
    });
  }
}
```

`tooltip.component.spec.ts`:

```js
import { fakeAsync, TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TooltipComponent } from './tooltip.component';

fdescribe('65212730', () => {
  it('should pass', fakeAsync(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TooltipComponent);
    const componentInst = fixture.componentInstance;
    componentInst.id = 'fieldId';
    const getStateStub = spyOn(componentInst, 'getState').and.stub();

    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick(50);

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(componentInst.container.nodeName).toBe('DIV');
      expect(componentInst.inputField.nodeName).toBe('INPUT');
      expect(getStateStub).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  }));
});
```

unit test result with coverage:

[image]

Comment: nice this works, but the function `getState()` is not covered and `this.container` and `this.inputField` properties are setted by a `querySelector` which both comes from another component on the DOM. You defined it now on the tooltip component. The `TooltipComponent` includes only the tooltip message. How can I cover the function `getState()`?

Comment: Because I stubbed `getState()` method and only test `ngOnInit` method.